# Unit testing if text == null

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am doing some unit tests with microsoft unit testing

I have this piece of code:

```
public void AddComment(Case c, string text)
        {
            if (text == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var comment = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<CaseComment>().Create();

            comment.Case = c;
            comment.Account = _userInfoProvider.UserName;
            comment.DateUtc = DateTimeHelper.UtcNow();
            comment.Text = text;

            UnitOfWork.GetRepository<CaseComment>().Insert(comment);
        }
```

And I have a Unit test for this piece of cdoe:

```
 if (text == null)
            {
                return;
            }
```

I the unit test like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void BaseProcess_Should_AddCommentIfNull()
        {
            string text = null;

            var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text);

            Assert.AreEqual(text, null);

        }
```

It shows green. But the code coverage is still yellow and not blue.

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void BaseProcess_Should_AddCommentIfNull()
        {
            string comment = "Comment";
            var newInstance = new Case
            {

                Reference = comment,                
                DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now,                      
                Status = CaseStatus.Submitted,
            };          

            string text = null;

            var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text);
            Action act = () => CorrectionRequestCaseProcess.AddComment(newInstance, comment);

            Assert.AreEqual(text, null);

        }
```

But if I do it like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void BaseProcess_Should_AddCommentIfNull()
        {
            string comment = "";
            var newInstance = new Case
            {

                Reference = comment,                
                DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now,                      
                Status = CaseStatus.Submitted,
            };          

            string text = null;

            var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text);
            Action act = () => CorrectionRequestCaseProcess.AddComment(newInstance, text);

            Assert.AreEqual(text, null);

        }
```

Nothing changed`enter code here`

And I wrote a other unit test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void BaseProcess_should_equalToNull()
{
    string comment = "Comment";
    var newInstance = new Case
    {

        Reference = comment,
        DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now,
        Status = CaseStatus.Submitted,
    };

    var newComment = new CaseComment();
    newComment.Case = newInstance;
    newComment.Account = _userInfoProvider.UserName;
    newComment.DateUtc = DateTimeHelper.UtcNow();
    newComment.Text = comment;

    var comment2 = _testUnitOfWork.GetRepository<CaseComment>().Create();
    _testUnitOfWork.GetRepository<CaseComment>().Insert(newComment);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your unit test call `AddComment`?

Comment: A unit test should **check the result (the return value) of a method call**, or it should **check the effect that the method call had on something measurable / observable** (e.g. simulated storage). But your test *doesn't even call the method*... so no wonder it shows the method as *not covered*.

Comment: You aren't actually testing `AddComment` being called with `null` or anything else for that matter. Your test has to do the operation (method call, property set, etc) and then `Assert` that this operation has had the expected effects. Asserting that a string set to `null` in the test itself is `null` tests nothing.

Comment: I edit the post with calling the method

Answer (score 0):

You should add an additional test case that text variable not equal to null and verify that repository invoked. After that, the coverage of the function will be %100.

Comment: Thank you. But can you give an example. Thank you